# connecting to a database in mySQL workbench

Tags: database, express, backend, mysql-workbench

code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 3306
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
so thats the error that keeps popping up. I guess it's because port 3306 is in use but how to i make it inactive so i can use it?

I tried editing my connection to a different port but it doesn't connect so i'm just stuck. I'm new to web dev so i'm trying to get my backend kicking